# Compare two large numeric vectors with multiple conditions without looping through

Tags: r

I have two large vectors of size ~ 100K with integer data in them e.g 0,1,2,3...70.
I want to compare these two vectors element by element with multiple conditions and put a value in 3rd vector bases on the condition. If I loop through this using a for loop and multiple if statements, it takes about 5 hours to run on a good power cluster. Is there a way I can speed it up or achieve the results without looping through?

Thanks.

Example:

```
A <- c(3,0,1,0,6,1,10,5,1,8,1,4) # 12 elements each
B <- c(1,0,5,1,0,2,2,4,0,1,2,10)
```

Conditions:

```
if(A[i]==1 && B[i]==1)
{
  C[i] <- "Alpha"
}
if(A[i]>=1 || B[i]>=1)
{
   if(A[i]>1 || B[i]>1)
  {
     C[i] <- "Bravo"
  }
}
if(A[i]==0 || B[i]==0)
{
   if(A[i]>=1 || B[i]>=1)
   {
     C[i] <- "Charlie"
   }
}
if(A[i]==0 && B[i]==0)
{
   C[i] <- "Delta"
}
```

Comment: You can use `ifelse()` which is is vectorized

Comment: Thanks. Used it like this   y <- ifelse(A==2 && B==1, "Normal", 0)  but returns only one value, probably compares the first elements only. Can you show an example please?

Comment: Note the difference between `&` and `&&`; look at `?'&'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your `for` loop version and the results match the following:

```
A <- c(3,0,1,0,6,1,10,5,1,8,1,4) # 12 elements each
B <- c(1,0,5,1,0,2,2,4,0,1,2,10)

C <- ifelse((A==1 & B==1), "Alpha", 
            ifelse((A==0 | B==0) & (A>=1 | B>=1), "Charlie",
                   ifelse((A>=1 | B>=1) & (A>1 | B>1), "Bravo",               
                          ifelse(A==0 & B==0, "Delta", NA))))

C

##  [1] "Bravo"   "Delta"   "Bravo"   "Charlie" "Charlie" "Bravo"   "Bravo"   "Bravo"   "Charlie" "Bravo"  
## [11] "Bravo"   "Bravo"
```

There's definitely a speed improvement, too:

```
set.seed(1492)

A <- sample(0:10, 100000, replace=TRUE)
B <- sample(0:10, 100000, replace=TRUE)

system.time(C <- ifelse((A==1 & B==1), "Alpha", 
            ifelse((A==0 | B==0) & (A>=1 | B>=1), "Charlie",
                   ifelse((A>=1 | B>=1) & (A>1 | B>1), "Bravo",               
                          ifelse(A==0 & B==0, "Delta", NA)))))

##  user  system elapsed 
## 0.350   0.004   0.354
```

The reason for the single `&` and `|` operators is straight from the R help:

> & and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR. The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.

Answer (score 2):

R is most efficient when you work with whole vectors at once, and let the underlying fortran/C take care of optimisation. So you could try something like:

```
  C <- rep("Alpha",length(A))
  C[(A>=1 | B>=1) & (A>1 | B>1)] <- "Bravo"
  C[(A==0 | B==0) & (A>=1 | B>=1)] <- "Charlie"
  C[A==0 & B==0] <- "Delta"
```

note `|` and `&` are vectorised versions of `||` and `&&` that compare elementwise (help is at `?'|'`)

Comment: I make this about 10 times faster than hrbrmstr's solution with the same dataset.

Comment: Does this compare elements in the same positions or one element against all elements of the other vector?