# Warnings on R code

Tags: r

I have this code (based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035152/1262767):

```
# Example vectors
mR1<- matrix(rnorm(1e6), nrow = 1e6, ncol = 1)
mRy<- matrix(rnorm(1e6), nrow = 1e6, ncol = 1)
mDMDuc1 <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), nrow = 1e6, ncol = 1)
mDMDc <- matrix(rnorm(1e6), nrow = 1e6, ncol = 1)
mp<- matrix(rnorm(1e6), nrow = 1e6, ncol = 1)

iters=100
mFR <- matrix(, nrow = 0, ncol = 1)

#perform a number of loops
for (j in 1:iters) {
#for each loop iterate thru the several vectors
  mFR3 <- matrix(, nrow = 1e6, ncol = 1)
  mp2 <- mp[sample(1:1e6, 1e6)]
#check conditions (by comparing the vectors' values with the same index), calculate result and assign it to mFR3
#mFR3 has values between 0 and 1
#avoid iterating thru vectors element by element since it is really slow so
#I used the whole vectors at once
  mFR3[mp2>mR1] <- 1
  mFR3[mp2<=mRy] <- 0
  mFR3[(mR1<mRy) | (mR1<0.005) |
         (mRy<0.005) | (mDMDuc1<1e4) |
         (mDMDc<1e7) | (mDMDc<mDMDuc1)] <- NA
  mFR3[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)] <- (((-(mDMDuc1/(1-mR1/mRy))/mRy)*mp2 + 
                                              (mDMDuc1/(1-mR1/mRy))) - 0)/(mDMDc - 0)
#store values of mFR3 in each loop
  mFR <- rbind(mFR,matrix(mFR3, ncol=1, nrow = 1e6))
}
colnames(mFR) <- "mFR"
#delete NA values
mFR <- mFR[rowSums(is.na(mFR)) != ncol(mFR),1]
```

But I got several warnings like this:

```
1: In mFR3[(mp2 > mRy) & (mp2 <= mR1)] <- (((-(mDMDuc1/(1 -  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
....
49: In mFR3[(mp2 > mRy) & (mp2 <= mR1)] <- (((-(mDMDuc1/(1 -  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
50: In mFR3[(mp2 > mRy) & (mp2 <= mR1)] <- (((-(mDMDuc1/(1 -  ... :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Based on MrFlick comment the warning shows up because `length(mFR3[(mp2 > mRy) & (mp2 <= mR1)]) != length(((-(mDMDuc1/(1 -  ...)`. Perhaps there is no problem with this if R assigns the right values to `mFR3` despite the difference in length. Therefore my questions are:

**1)** Does R correctly assign values to `mFR3` (i.e. given the condition `(mp2 > mRy) & (mp2 <= mR1)` is true will it assign the value at the right index to `mFR3`)?

**2)** If not, what's the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You're getting that error because `length(mFR3[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)]) != length((((-(mDMDuc1/(1-mR1/mRy))/mRy)*mp2 + (mDMDuc1/(1-mR1/mRy))) - 0)/(mDMDc - 0))` But i don't know what you want to do about that; you didn't provide any context or description for your problem. If you would have ran this line-by-line you should have been able to discover what line was causing the error.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I just want to check if some conditions are fulfilled and assign different values to mFR3 (mFR). Any suggestion to make this work? Thanks

Comment: Honestly it's completely unclear to me what your code is supposed to do. You didn't provide any desired output so I have no idea what it would look like when it was "working." I can't just "fix" the code if I don't know what it's supposed to do, and really such questions are off topic. You should be better able to describe your exact problem.

Comment: I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just replaced

```
mFR3[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)] <- (((-(mDMDuc1/(1-mR1/mRy))/mRy)*mp2 + 
                                              (mDMDuc1/(1-mR1/mRy))) - 0)/(mDMDc - 0)
```

with

```
mFR3[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)] <- (((-(mDMDuc1[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)]/(1-mR1[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)]/mRy[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)]))
                                     /mRy[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)])*mp2[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)] + 
                                              (mDMDuc1[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)]/(1-mR1[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)]/mRy[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)])))
                                   - 0)/(mDMDc[(mp2>mRy) & (mp2<=mR1)] - 0)
```

to just use the right vector indices! Ugly but it works like a charm and very very fast when compared with for loops